# Formula for the derivative of finite power series in reversed order of terms.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, power-series, legendre-polynomials

I wanted to solve the polar part in Schrödinger's wave equation for the H-atom by direct substitution of functions of form:-
$$
\Theta_{lm}(\theta) = a_{lm} \sin^{|m|}\theta \sum_{r≥0}^{r≤(l-|m|)/2}(-1)^rb_r \cos^{l-|m|-2r}\theta
$$
The $a$'s are normalisation constants, no problem there. However, the problem of determining the $b$'s ultimately drops down to finding the first and second derivatives of the polynomial in $z=\cos \theta$:
$$
P(z)=\sum_{r≥0}^{r≤(l-|m|)/2} (-1)^rb_r z^{l-|m|-2r}
$$
Which is a finite power series written in decreasing order of powers. I couldn't find a formula for so (well sometimes I get that dumb), but I think it does exist, maybe some reference book or website. I emphasize that what I'm doing is right the reverse of Frobenius-method. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a finite power series, it's basically just a sum. You can differentiate it term by term (which you could also do for infinite power series, btw, it's just harder to prove in that case).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, Hey, I got it. You are right. Maybe I just rewrite the sum as a power series and differentiate, and I'm done. Thanks for the help!!